# How to apply observer pattern if observers are also subjects

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a container panel.
In the container I have n other panels. The user can change the information in any panel. When a panel changes, all other containers should be updated and refresh the information they present.

In a normal situation the observer patter has a single subject and a bunch of observers. In this case the observers are also subjects.

Is this something design patterns can address ? How should I build the interaction between these objects in a good OOP style ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern might be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like the [pub/sub pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34316/Topic-based-Publish-Subscribe-design-pattern-imple) than the observer pattern.

- Panel A, B and C subscribes on topic X.
- Panel B generates topic Z when it have received hand handled topic X

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the idea of the observer pattern by just making it many-to-many. The only difference is that the observer needs to know WHAT subject changed state rather than ANY subject has changed state.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a container class instance C1 and Observer class instance ob1, ob2, ob3 all observing Subject class instance s1. When an event occurs on ob1 you could trigger an event in class S1 and ensure the event handler function in S1 notfies observer ob1, ob2, ob3

Hope this helps. Please let me know if it does :)

Thanks!